# How can I access json value into C#?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an array, which is from API, and I am not able to change API response. So following is response and I want to access it,

```
{ 
   "status":"success",
   "data":{ 
      "2019":{ 
         "11":{ 
            "consecutive":[ 
               [ 
                  11,
                  12
               ],
               [ 
                  19,
                  20,
                  21
               ],
               [ 
                  24,
                  25,
                  26
               ]
            ],
            "non_consecutive":[ 

            ]
         },
         "12":{ 
            "consecutive":[ 
               [  ],
               [  ]
            ],
            "non_consecutive":[ 
               4
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Suppose `xVarible` has this array, so how can I access `11,12` and other values? I am not C# developer, I am here asking this question for someone else. Kindly guide me about it, I would appreciate.

**After Requesting** I added Script

```
dynamic gamePlayLogsResponse = JSONObject.Parse(userGameLogs.downloadHandler.text);
JsonData gameplayLogsData = new JsonData();
gameplayLogsData = JsonMapper.ToObject(gamePlayLogsResponse);
totalUnlockedLevels = 1;
if (gamePlayLogsResponse["status"] == "success")
{
    int yearsLength = gamePlayLogsResponse["data"].Count;
    for (int x = 0; x < yearsLength; x++)
    {
        if (CalendarController.year == "2019")
        {
            for (int y = 1; y <= 12; y++)
            {
                Debug.Log(CalendarController.month + "     " + y.ToString());
                if (CalendarController.month == y.ToString())
                {
                    int consectiveLength = gamePlayLogsResponse["data"][CalendarController.year][CalendarController.month]["consecutive"].Count;
                    Debug.Log("consectiveLength     " + consectiveLength);
                    for (int z = 0; z < consectiveLength; z++)
                    {
                        int totalConsective = (int)gamePlayLogsResponse["data"][CalendarController.year][CalendarController.month]["consecutive"][z].Count;
                        for (int i = 0; i < totalConsective; i++)
                        {
                            Debug.Log(gamePlayLogsResponse["data"][CalendarController.year][CalendarController.month]["consecutive"][i]);
                            if (i == 0)
                                calenderController._dateItems[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = consStartSprite;
                            if (i > 1 && i < totalConsective - 1)
                                calenderController._dateItems[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = consContinueSprite;
                            if (i == totalConsective - 1)
                                calenderController._dateItems[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = consEndSprite;
                            Debug.Log(calenderController._dateItems[i].name);
                        }
                    }
                    int nonConsectiveLength = gamePlayLogsResponse["data"][CalendarController.year][CalendarController.month]["non_consecutive"].Count;
                    Debug.Log("nonConsectiveLength     " + nonConsectiveLength);
                    for (int j = 0; j < nonConsectiveLength; j++)
                    {
                        int totalNonconsective = (int)gamePlayLogsResponse["data"][CalendarController.year][CalendarController.month]["non_consecutive"][j].Count;
                        for (int k = 0; j < totalNonconsective; k++)
                        {
                            calenderController._dateItems[k].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = nonConsSprite;
                            Debug.Log(gamePlayLogsResponse["data"][CalendarController.year][CalendarController.month]["non_consecutive"][k]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @xdtTransform thank you, can you explain bit more please ?

Comment: The final class should look like `public class RootObject
{
 [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string status { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, MeaningfullName> > Data { get; set; }
}

public partial class MeaningfullName
{
 [JsonProperty("consecutive")]
 public long[][] Consecutive { get; set; }

 [JsonProperty("non_consecutive")]
 public long[] NonConsecutive { get; set; }
}` Typing on phone.

Comment: Basically when you have a JSON object property name that have a usefull value. It must ring a bell , "Look this property name look like a value" => "It's a dictionary !" .

Comment: @xdtTransform thanks, I will follow the instructions, I also added part of script that is using for accessing the value from json

Comment: Do you have controle over the generation of the Json? Why don't you return a 2 List of DateTime. . . The logic will be really simple..

Comment: @xdtTransform I am trying to highlight consecutive or other dates in calendar accordingly.

Comment: @xdtTransform can you please fix my issue, i would appreciate.

Comment: @ImranAbbas, 2 solutions: either map the json to the correct class. And don't use dynamic . Or Change the object response to be 2 list of datetime. So you don't have to play arround with nested weird stuff.

Comment: I don't see how the previous comment stating the correct class structure didn't helped. Using it accessing data is simple like https://dotnetfiddle.net/jLAleB. For you logic block I just don't get what you are trying to do. Too much poorly named variable, convertion from string to int and int to string. And loop. goinh thought all month from years 0, for just 5 dates. Really you should look into DateTime it's really nice to store Year/Month/Day data. And usable.

Comment: Can someone kindly help me, I would appreciate.

Comment: isnt the fiddle link with the whole demo not enought?

Comment: @xdtTransform why don't you post as answer, with some minor tweaks OP should just be able to cut'n'paste into their app.

Comment: Ideally @ImranAbbas, get your developer to post their issues in SO so that we can communicate directly with them, this isn't a very well constructed question because there is no mention of the actual problems or errors that you have encountered, so while we can try to re-write your code for you, SO is not designed to be a free code writing service.

Answer (score 4):

> [@xdtTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9260725/xdttransform) has a really well constructed fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jLAleB
>   The key takeaway is to recognize that all *JSON* objects can be deserialized or otherwise represented in C# as `Dictionary<string, object>`

OP is going to struggle to implement without prior C# knowledge, importantly the fiddle requires the [Newtonsoft.Json (Json.NET)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/) NuGet package, but it is great advice, Op should consider using serialization to solve this problem as the effort required is greatly reduced and the code simplified.

> What OP *didn't* mention is that this is for UWP, in UWP we can still use Json.NET, but there is also the native [Windows.Data.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json) API available for formatting and parsing Json when you don't feel like using Json.NET.

## Solution using [Windows.Data.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json)

> `CalendarController` holds the current user selections, this is the navigation controller, probably a standard calendar interface.

The main change here is that instead of iterating through the dictionary until you find the element that matches the properties in `CalendarController`, because it is a dictionary (JsonObject) we can use the indexer to navigate there directly.

Because the data item might not be present, `GetNamedObject` with a `null` default value was used to obtain the `year` and `month` variables.

```
var gamePlayLogsResponse = JsonObject.Parse(userGameLogs.downloadHandler.text);
totalUnlockedLevels = 1;
if (gamePlayLogsResponse["status"].GetString() == "success")
{
    var data = gamePlayLogsResponse["data"].GetObject();

    // get the data for the selected year, if there is any
    var year = data.GetNamedObject(CalendarController.year, null);
    if (year != null)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Found data for selected year: {CalendarController.year}");
        // get the data for the selected month, if there is any
        var month = year.GetNamedObject(CalendarController.month, null);
        if (month != null)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Found data for selected month: {CalendarController.month}");
            var consecutive = month["consecutive"].GetArray();
            Debug.Log($"consectiveLength     {consecutive.Count}");
            foreach (var groupObject in consecutive)
            {
                var group = groupObject.GetArray();
                int totalConsective = group.Count;
                for(int i = 0; i < totalConsective; i ++)
                {
                    var day = Convert.ToInt32(group[i].GetNumber());
                    Debug.Log($"Day {i}: {day}");
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Show start of consecutive block in the calendar");
                        CalendarController._dateItems[day].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = consStartSprite;
                    }
                    if (i > 1 && i < totalConsective - 1)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Show middle of consecutive block in calendar");
                        CalendarController._dateItems[day].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = consContinueSprite;
                    }
                    if (i == totalConsective - 1)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Show end of consecutive block in calendar");
                        CalendarController._dateItems[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = consEndSprite;
                        Debug.Log(CalendarController._dateItems[i].name);
                    }
                }
            }

            var nonConsecutive = month["non_consecutive"].GetArray();
            Debug.Log($"nonConsectiveLength     {nonConsecutive.Count}");
            foreach (var dayObject in nonConsecutive)
            {
                var day = Convert.ToInt32(dayObject.GetNumber());

                Debug.Log("Show non-consecutive block in calendar");
                CalendarController._dateItems[day].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = nonConsSprite;
                Debug.Log($"Day: {day}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log($"NO DATA for selected month: {CalendarController.month}");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log($"NO DATA for selected year: {CalendarController.year}");
    }
}
```

## Json.NET Solution following guidance provided by [@xdtTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9260725/xdttransform)

This solution deserialzes the JSON into a typed interface, this allows for less "magic strings" and makes the code easier to follow.

1. Install [Newtonsoft.Json (Json.NET)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/) NuGet package.
2. Use the following code snippet to declare the minimal classes to represent your JSON structure.

   ```
   public class gamePlayLogs
   {
       [JsonProperty("status")]
       public string status { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty("data")]
       public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Month>> Data { get; set; }
   }

   public partial class Month
   {
       [JsonProperty("consecutive")]
       public int[][] Consecutive { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty("non_consecutive")]
       public int[] NonConsecutive { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. The following is the same snippet of code, using the references to the new concrete classes that were added:

   ```
   var gamePlayLogsResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<gamePlayLogs>(userGameLogs.downloadHandler.text);
   totalUnlockedLevels = 1;
   if (gamePlayLogsResponse.status == "success")
   {
       if (gamePlayLogsResponse.Data.TryGetValue(CalendarController.year, out Dictionary<string, Month> year))
       {
           Debug.Log($"Found data for selected year: {CalendarController.year}");
           // get the data for the selected month, if there is any
           if (year.TryGetValue(CalendarController.month, out Month month))
           {
               Debug.Log($"Found data for selected month: {CalendarController.month}");
               Debug.Log($"consectiveLength     {month.Consecutive.Length}");
               foreach (var group in month.Consecutive)
               {
                   for (int i = 0; i < group.Length; i++)
                   {
                       var day = group[i];
                       Debug.Log($"Day {i}: {day}");
                       if (i == 0)
                       {
                           Debug.Log("Show start of consecutive block in the calendar");
                           CalendarController._dateItems[day].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = consStartSprite;
                       }
                       if (i > 1 && i < group.Length - 1)
                       {
                           Debug.Log("Show middle of consecutive block in calendar");
                           CalendarController._dateItems[day].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = consContinueSprite;
                       }
                       if (i == group.Length - 1)
                       {
                           Debug.Log("Show end of consecutive block in calendar");
                           CalendarController._dateItems[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = consEndSprite;
                           Debug.Log(CalendarController._dateItems[i].name);
                       }
                   }
               }

               Debug.Log($"nonConsectiveLength     {month.NonConsecutive.Length}");
               foreach (var day in month.NonConsecutive)
               {
                   Debug.Log("Show non-consecutive block in calendar");
                   CalendarController._dateItems[day].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = nonConsSprite;
                   Debug.Log($"Day: {day}");
               }
           }
           else
           {
               Debug.Log($"NO DATA for selected month: {CalendarController.month}");
           }

       }
       else
       {
           Debug.Log($"NO DATA for selected year: {CalendarController.year}");
       }
   }
   ```

> A few assumptions were made regarding data types and miss-spellings in member names. in particular there are references to `CalendarController` and `calenderController` that have been assumed to be the same thing. This code is provided 'as is' WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED. It is expected to be used only as a guiding reference for OP to complete their task, or indeed to pass on those who will do so on their behalf.